# Make file not show anything in console

Tags: javascript, php, css, html

Can we prevent website to do not show any error or warning, anything in F12/console?

Because i have some trick to protect content with html that will show a warning in console so everyone will know how can i do that and can steal my content.

Thanks.

Comment: Don't expect that you can *secure* your content once you put it online...

Comment: You can add some javascript to prevent right click and `f12` button press.

Comment: You do not have any tricks that can protect anything when you put it on the web.

Comment: I disagree with the closing reason. OP is obviously doing something stup... doomed to failure but the question itself isn't unclear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. If someone wants to view your client side javascript, they will - once it's downloaded to the browser, it's out of your control, and on the end user's machine, visible by the browser and other client side tools.

You can (a) slow them down by obfuscating your code, or you can (b) run the code you want to protect on the server side and just send the results to the client.

Comment: How can i run on server side, can you gift me some infomation?

Comment: Php is a server side language (all php code is evaluated on the server before it is sent to the client), and is probably simplest to get started with. If you want, you could also try [node.js](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/node-js-server-side-javascript/) for server side javascript.